# Доделать JQuery скрипт

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите пожалуйста!
Получается эффект аккордеона, при нажатии на ссылку появляется section потом, при нажатии на ссылку ниже открывается другой section а предыдущий закрывается.

Подскажите что нужно добавить чтобы и сама ссылка скрывалась при нажатии на неё а при нажатии на другую ссылку она появлялась, также как и section.

есть такой html

```
<ul class="vac-list">
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="vac-show"></a>
    <section>12</section>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="vac-show"></a>
    <section>34</section>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="vac-show"></a>
    <section>56</section>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="vac-show"></a>
    <section>78</section>
  </li>
</ul>
```

и JS скрипт

```
(function($) {

  var allPanels = $('.vac-list section').hide();

  $('.vac-list .vac-show').click(function() {
    allPanels.slideUp();
    $(this).siblings('section').slideDown();
    return false;
  });

})(jQuery);
```

Получается эффект аккордеона, при нажатии на ссылку появляется section потом, при нажатии на ссылку ниже открывается другой section а предыдущий закрывается.

Подскажите что нужно добавить чтобы и сама ссылка скрывалась при нажатии на неё а при нажатии на другую ссылку она появлялась, также как и section.

Буду очень признателен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вот так

```
 (function($) {
    var $vac_list = $(".vac-list"),
        $section  = $vac_list.find("section"),
        $all_li   = $vac_list.find("li"),
        $show     = $vac_list.find(".vac-show");

    $show.click(function() {
        var $this       = $(this),
            $this_block = $this.parents("li").find("section");

        // Сворачиваем всё открытое
        $section.slideUp();

        // Показываем скрытую кнопку
        $show.removeClass("hidden");

        // Скрываем кнопку
        $this.addClass("hidden");

        // Разворачиваем нужное
        $this_block.slideDown();

        return false;
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Подробнее тут https://jsfiddle.net/ragjy83w/1/

Comment: Спасибо, все работает!